# how to pass callback to filter that has access to results of filter

Tags: javascript

I want to run another function immediately after the filter as shown below that has access to the results of the filter. The anonymous function I pass doesn't run.  I know that you can chain a map to a filter, but I don't want to iterate over the array one by one after filter, just have access to the whole array at once. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/hrpbuvhf/2/)

```
var vegetables = ["kale", "brocoli", "kale"];

class Vegies {
  constructor(vegetables) {
    this.vegies = vegetables.filter(function(v){
         return v.length > 3;
    }, function(){
        console.log(this.vegies.length, "doesn't run");
    });
  }

};
var n = new Vegies(["kale", "banana"]);
```

Comment: That's because filter doesn't take a callback function. Just use `this.vegies` after the filter? It's synchronous...

Comment: Are you talking about like this? https://jsfiddle.net/8fk94t5r/

Comment: That's the correct way to do it. It's just that you have `length > 3` and all the items in your array have lengths greater than 3 so nothing gets filtered out.

Comment: @DonovanM - The `v.length` is on the string in the array item, not the array.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yep. I meant that all of the strings in the array have more than 3 characters so they all are returned from the `.filter` method. If you change it to `v.length > 4` you will see that only "brocoli" is returned.

Answer (score -1):

Should do the job ;)

```
var vegetables = ["kale", "brocoli", "kale"];

var filteredVegies = vegetables.filter(function myFilter(v){
   return v.length > 3;
});

console.log(filteredVegies) // runs after the filtering..
```

#### asyncFilter

However, maybe the intention was to filter some bigger collections in an async way, so in that case, this could be interesting:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-async-filter

Comment: I am pretty sure it's the second passed in function to `.filter()` that's the issue, not the first (which works as is).

Comment: that's not what I was hoping to do. See @AndrewLi's comment under the OP for my intention.